# Submartingale under equivalent change of probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, finance

**Setting** We work on a filtered probability space with finite time horizon $T$ and let $Q$ be a probability measure equivalent to $P$. Let $\rho_t=E[dQ/dP |\mathcal{F}_t]$, then $\rho$ is a martingale.

**Result** A process $M$ is a $Q$-martingale if and only if $\rho M$ is a $P$-martingale. See for example Lemma 5.3.4 in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-68121-2).

**Question** Does the same hold if we replace "martingale" by "submartingale", i.e. is $M$ a $Q$-submartingale if and only if $\rho M$ is a $P$-submartingale?

**Proof** (this is the proof of Lemma 5.3.4 in the above book adapted to the submartingale setting) Let $M$ be a $Q$-submartingale. Then $E[|\rho_t M_t|]=E[\rho_T |M_t|]=E_Q[|M_t|]<\infty$, showing that $\rho_t M_t$ is $P$-integrable. Next, for $s\leq t$ and $A\in\mathcal{F}_s$,
$$E[\rho_tM_t1_A]=E[\rho_TM_t1_A]=E_Q[M_t1_A]\geq E_Q[M_s 1_A]=E[\rho_T M_s 1_A]=E[\rho_sM_s 1_A].$$ *It is not clear if the next step is indeed true.* Thus $E[\rho_tM_t|\mathcal{F}_s]\geq \rho_sM_s$, showing that $\rho M$ is a $P$-submartingale.

**Proof** (of the step) Let $N :=\rho M$. We know $E[(N_t-N_s)1_A]\geq 0, \forall A\in\mathcal{F}_s$. Define $D:=\{E[N_t|\mathcal{F}_s]-N_s=E[N_t-N_s|\mathcal{F}_s]<0\}\in\mathcal{F}_s$. Thus
$$0\leq E[(N_t-N_s)1_D]=E[E[N_t-N_s|\mathcal{F}_s]1_D].$$
This implies $P[D]=0$ and thus $E[N_t|\mathcal{F}_s]\geq N_s$ a.s.

Comment: Yet some new incomprehensible and nonsensical close votes ...

Comment: @TheBridge . I voted to close *before* hannah added her Proof. Missing context and other details. Homework like. No own attempt. Meanwhile I totally changed my mind.

Comment: @hannah . You are showing correctly that $E_P[\rho_tM_t1_A]\ge E_P[\rho_sM_s1_A]$ for all $A\in{\cal F}_s$. I am having doubts that this implies $E_P[\rho_tM_t|{\cal F}_s]\ge \rho_sM_s$. What we know is that the $=$ sign implies the $=$ sign. Please elaborate.

Comment: @KurtG. I jumped to this conclusion without thinking about it thouroughly. I thought about it now, but cannot prove why it should hold.

Comment: Neither can I . Let's keep this on our radar . BTW this question here is the first one of yours that I see which -as far as I can tell- ( I haven't looked all of them in detail ) shows a *real* research interest . You asked a nice and right question .

Comment: @KurtG. I think I proved why it holds. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: Why is $P[D]=0$ ? Clearly $D\in{\cal F}_s$ and $E[N_t1_D]\ge E[N_s1_D]$ . Then I am stuck.

Comment: @KurtG. If $P[D]>0$, then $0\leq E[E[N_t-N_s|\mathcal{F}_s]1_D]<0$, contradiction.

Comment: I would believe that if we knew that $E[N_t-N_s|{\cal F_s}]<-\varepsilon<0$ for some $\varepsilon >0$. Trying alternatively $0\le E[(N_t-N_s)1_D]$ would require $N_t-N_s<-\varepsilon<0$.

Comment: @KurtG. I don't think we need the condition with the $\epsilon$. If you integrate something that is strictly negative over an event with strict positive probability, then the result is strictly negative. This yields a contradiction to $P[D]>0$.

Comment: That's absolutely convincing. And I found the error in my previous answer ! Congratulations !

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you think is correct !

I update my previously wrong answer that now shows a failing attempt to construct a counterexample. As I always do I mixed up $P$- and $Q$-martingale. Hopefully not anymore.

With a $Q$-Brownian motion $W_t$ the proces $M_t=e^{W_t}$ is a $Q$-submartingale.

Let the Radon-Nikodym density of $Q$ w.r.t. $P$ be the $Q$-martingale
$$
\frac{dP}{dQ}=e^{aW_t-a^2t/2}\,.
$$
The inverse of this is the $P$-martingale
$$
\rho_t=\frac{dQ}{dP}=e^{-aW_t+a^2t/2}=e^{-a(W_t+at)-a^2t/2}
$$
where $W_t+at$ is a $P$-Brownian motion by Girsanov's theorem.

The process
$$
\rho_t\,M_t=e^{(1-a)W_t+a^2t/2}=e^{(1-a)(W_t+at)-(1-a)\,at+a^2t/2}
$$
is under $P$ the product of the $P$-martingale $X_t:=e^{(1-a)(W_t+at)-(1-a)^2t/2}$ and the deterministic function
$$
Y_t:=e^{(1-a)^2t/2-(1-a)\,at+a^2t/2}=e^{\textstyle\frac{1-2a+a^2-a+a^2+a^2}{2}\scriptstyle t}=e^{\textstyle\frac{1-3a+3a^2}{2}\scriptstyle t}.
$$
This function is strictly increasing in $t$ for every $a$.
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb E_P[\rho_tM_t|{\cal F}_s]=\mathbb E_P[X_tY_t|{\cal F}_s]=X_sY_t>X_sY_s=\rho_sM_s.
$$
That is, $\rho_tM_t$ is a $P$-submartingale.

Comment: @Thank you. However, I do not see why there is a mistake in the proof I added.

Comment: Neither do I. Except that you are showing that $\rho M$ is a $P$-**sub**martingale (typo). Will get back to this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo!